# FileStream and memory usage

Tags: .net, file-io, .net-4.0, memory-management, filestream

I've written the following program which purpose is to create a file of a give size with some random data in it. The program works fine and does what it's suppose to do. However, I don't understand why it consumes 5GB of RAM (see screenshot of my Task Manager). While I am writing the file with random data, I am not creating new objects. What am I missing? I would expect this program to take no memory at all.

The big problem I have right now is that in the middle on the file generation, the machine is dying...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateFile("test.dat", 10 * 1024 * 1024);
    }

    public static void CreateFile(string path, long approximativeFileSizeInKb)
    {
        RandomNumberGenerator randomNumber = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

        byte[] randomData = new byte[64 * 1024];

        int numberOfIteration = 0;
        randomNumber.GetNonZeroBytes(randomData);

        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path, 64 * 1024))
        {
            while (numberOfIteration++ * 64 < approximativeFileSizeInKb)
            {
                fs.Write(randomData, 0, randomData.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just tried your program and upon start I see an increase of ~1GB. Then memory use stays there until the end.

Comment: Gonzalo - Glad to hear that... But that's still a lot of RAM to write on the disk? Are you x86 or x64?

Comment: The big problem I have right now is that in the middle on the file generation, the machine is dying...

Comment: Can you show us all the memory related columns for this process as shown in the Process tab? Working set, pagefile use, etc...

Comment: I don't know about the memory issue, but I'm curious about the random data. Is there a particular reason for using RandomNumberGenerator, which is probably slower and has more overhead than System.Random? Also you repeat the same random 64 KiB block all over again and omit null bytes, which seems a bit odd in conjunction with a cryptographically safe random number generator.

Comment: Gnafoo - I am using the RandomNumberGenerator because it has a method which populate a byte array. No other reason than that.

Comment: System.Random has a NextBytes(byte[]) method that will do the same. Though it can emit null bytes, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your line which reads:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path, 64 * 1024))
```

to

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path, 64 * 1024, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
```

and see how that does for you.

Comment: Awesome! With that flag, the RAM stays super flat... :D I am happy. It seems a little slower thought..

Comment: It's the classic trade-off of speed vs. space.  You can likely re-gain some speed by tweaking your 2nd parameter to be more than 64Kb.  Though try to keep it on a 4Kb boundary to match Windows default memory page size.

Comment: Wow, all that RAM and intentionally not using it.  This is criminal.  -1, and I don't whip that out often on an answer.

Comment: Really?  For directly addressing his exact need, it gets voted down?  I don't see downvotes on the other answers which give the same advice.

Comment: I needed something that doesn't eat up all the RAM on the machine. Thank you Jesse. You answered my question.

Comment: So just to clarify using FIleOptions.WriteThrough can help with problems in your memory spking at the cost of speed because caching is off?

Answer (score 5):

File system writes are always buffered by the OS.

You are calling FileSystem.Write faster than your hardware can handle the writes, thus the OS is caching all of your writes.

Even if you called FileSystem.Flush, you would still be writing faster than your hardware can handle the writes.

Get a faster hard disk subsystem.  Preferrable an RAID controller with lots of on board memory connected to a large RAID 5 or 6 array with server based hard drives with 64MB caches set with write buffering.

(To alleviate this behavior add the flag `FileOptions.WriteThrough` to your File.Create call.)

Answer (score 1):

Windows seems to be using file system caching... it's not the app

Answer (score 1):

I pieced this together from various sites....The issue is Windows still caches everything even with writethrough option. So, your "Free" memory goes down if you use standard FileStream, which can be problematic if trying to do certain things with extremely large files and capturing high rate data at the same time.  Windows still has files cached when you close your app, btw.  This is good for files you want to write and forget about...which .Net doesn't seem to think you need.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("KERNEL32", SetLastError = true)]
        public extern static int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern unsafe IntPtr CreateFile(
            string FileName,           // file name 
            uint DesiredAccess,        // access mode 
            uint ShareMode,            // share mode 
            IntPtr SecurityAttributes, // Security Attr 
            uint CreationDisposition,  // how to create 
            uint FlagsAndAttributes,   // file attributes 
            IntPtr hTemplate // template file   
            );
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const uint FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000;
            const uint FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x80000000;
            Random r = new Random(0);
            IntPtr f = CreateFile(@"e:\test\temp.bin",
                             (uint)FileAccess.Write,
                             (uint)FileShare.None,
                             IntPtr.Zero,
                             (uint)FileMode.Create,
                              FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
                             IntPtr.Zero);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(f,FileAccess.Write,false,1024*1024))
            {
                int blocksize = 1024 * 1024;
                byte[] val = new byte[blocksize];
                for (int i = 0; i < blocksize; i++)
                {
                    val[i] = 1;
                }
                while (true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < blocksize; j++)
                        {
                            fs.WriteByte(val[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter s to stop");
                    ConsoleKeyInfo k = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (k.KeyChar == 's')
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            CloseHandle(f);
            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The FileStream maintains a memory buffer, allowing your program to output as fast as it can. Your program can stuff data into the buffer MUCH faster than that buffer can be written to disk, which is where the memory jump comes in.

The memory actually used does seem more than a little off, though; you're generating a 10MB file (in 64KB chunks) and using about 5GB of memory to do so. Is there anything else to this program than what's in the code snippet? Are you running it multiple times?

Comment: It's actually 10GB (read the code carefully), which would explain the caching going on of the machine has lots of unused memory.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gonzalo, I ran your code on my system and only saw a 1GB increase in memory usage.

Do you have anti-virus turned on?  The AV may be scanning the .dat file as it's being written, causing the data to be buffered in memory while the scan takes place, which causes the huge increase in memory usage.  If you suspect AV to be part of the problem, try changing the file extension to something other than .dat (e.g. .txt).

Another thing to try is adding a call to fs.Flush() after fs.Write(...).

Comment: I have no AV. I changed the file name to TXT and added Flush. No change in the behavior. :(